# How to find sequences of numbers such that their sum equals a given number

Tags: math

I have a problem like this:
Prints out 8 incremental numbers with the sum unchanged.
Example n = 57
then those 8 numbers are 1 3 4 6 8 9 12 14.
So can anyone help me with this problem.
Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static void eightIncrementalNumbers(int sum) {
    if (sum < 36) throw new IllegalArgumentException("sum");
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; sum -= i++)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

And

```
eightIncrementalNumbers(57);
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 29
```